# Understanding SQL efficiency

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlperformance

I'm looking at an old query I didn't write that is written in a format that I don't usually use. So I just rewrote it, it returns the exact same data, but it executes in 40 seconds and the original code in 14 seconds. Which intrigued me, I also looked at the explain plan tab to find out more.

My query's cardinality is 185,000 as the old query is 416. Why is my query not as efficient?

**Old query**

```
SELECT C.ID,
   C.DATE_ADDED AS C_DATE,
   G.DATE_ADDED AS G_DATE,
   DECODE (C.CPATH, NULL, 'N', 'Y') AS LINKED,
   ABS (ROUND (TO_NUMBER (G.DATE_ADDED - C.DATE_ADDED))) AS DIFF
FROM VT_C_REC C, VT_G_PATH G
WHERE     C.ID = G.C_ID
   AND (   (    C.CPATH IS NOT NULL
            AND C.CPATH = G.C_ID
            AND C.DATE_ADDED <> G.DATE_ADDED)
        OR (    C.CPATH IS NULL
            AND ABS (ROUND (TO_NUMBER (G.DATE_ADDED - C.DATE_ADDED))) <= 6))
   AND TO_DATE (C.DATE_ADDED, 'YYYYMMDD') >
          TO_DATE ('20070101', 'yyyymmdd')
   AND G.DEL_DT IS NULL
   AND C.DEL_DT IS NULL
```

**New query**

```
SELECT C.ID,
   C.DATE_ADDED AS C_DATE,
   G.DATE_ADDED AS G_DATE,
   CASE C.CPATH
        WHEN NULL THEN 'N'
        ELSE 'Y'
   END AS LINKED,
   ABS (ROUND(TO_NUMBER(G.DATE_ADDED - C.DATE_ADDED))) AS DIFF

FROM VT_C_REC C INNER JOIN VT_G_PATH G
    ON C.ID = G.C_ID

WHERE TO_DATE(C.DATE_ADDED, 'YYYYMMDD') >  TO_DATE('20070101', 'yyyymmdd')
AND G.DEL_DT IS NULL 
AND C.DEL_DT IS NULL
AND (
    (
        C.CPATH IS NOT NULL
        AND C.CPATH = G.C_ID
        AND C.DATE_ADDED != G.DATE_ADDED
    )  
OR  (
     C.CPATH IS NULL
     AND ABS(ROUND(TO_NUMBER(G.DATE_ADDED - C.DATE_ADDED))) <= 6
    )
);
```

If any one could help me understand that would be great.

Comment: The major difference that I can see would be you using a `CASE` rather than a `DECODE`. The `JOIN` you use should not perform slower than the old-fashioned `WHERE a.id = b.id`. Try replacing the `CASE` with the `DECODE` again and see if that helps?

Comment: @SchmitzIT if I replace my `CASE` with `DECODE` it runs in the same amount time ( I glanced at the wrong column tab)

Comment: Did you rule out caching by running the new one twice?

Comment: @DanBracuk Ran them back to back, still the same timing

Comment: @Jonnny Just saw the bit about cardinality. It might be that the order of the columns in the old query has been set specifically because of the uniqueness of the values. Try and see whether it helps if you simply replace the new `WHERE` clause with the old one (minus the `C.ID = G.C_ID` bit). If that speeds things up, there's your answer.

Comment: Look at the execution plans to see if they are the same.  I could imagine that with such complicated `join` conditions, the optimizer might choose two different paths for equivalent logic.

Comment: If your cardinality is changing that much, it suggests that you need to refresh statistics on the tables/columns/indexes, and/or you need to make sure the fields you are joining/filtering on have appropriate indexes in the first place. These two things can make 1000x more difference than the efficiency of `CASE` vs `DECODE`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The plans are not the same, the older quicker query performs a #HASH Join with cardinality of 416 occured and joins steps 9 & 12 which were `VT_C_REC C` and `VT_G_PATH`. My query's plan says a view definition was processed with a cardinality of 185,000, then a #HASH JOIN steps 8 + 10 were joined and it accessed the same table twice on an indexed column. This particular table that is pretty big 6M rows

Comment: @SchmitzIT If I completely remove the `WHERE` clause in my query then it returns the same cardinality, cost, plan and time.

Comment: This `WHERE TO_DATE(C.DATE_ADDED, 'YYYYMMDD') > TO_DATE('20070101', 'yyyymmdd')` can be quicker written as `WHERE C.DATE_ADDED > 20070101`. Althought dates should be stored as `DATE` type rather than numbers you can do the comparison in this case with numbers.